# bash - split string into array WITH empty values

Tags: bash, text, split, pattern-matching

```
pattern="::a::b::"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS="::"
read -r -a extractees <<< $pattern
IFS=$oldIFS
```

this results in

```
{"a","b"}
```

however, I need to maintain the indices, so I want

```
{"","a","b",""}
```

(for comparison, if I wanted `{"a","b"}`, I would have written `"a::b"`.

Why? because these elements are later split again (on a different delimiter) and the empty `""` values should result in an empty list *then*.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Cyrus ``{"","a","b",""}`` - as I have written in the post itself. ``{"","a","","b",""}`` makes no sense if ``::`` is the delimiter *and* it changes the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No field separator can be longer than 1 character, unfortunately, so `'::' → ':'`.

Aside of that, globbing should be explicitly turned off to prevent potential filename expansion in an unquoted variable.

```
set -f # disable globbing
pattern=":a:b c:"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
extractees=($pattern)
IFS=$oldIFS

echo "'${extractees[0]}'"
echo "'${extractees[1]}'"
echo "'${extractees[2]}'"
echo "'${extractees[3]}'"
```

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions are also not a reliable way to split a string into an array.

Comment: @chepner okay. `$IFS` is already set, so the only thing that can affect unquoted expansion is filename globbing. However, it does not occur here; just tried on BASH 4.3. Don\`t know what the exact reason is, this case is seemingly undocumented. But to be on the safe side, globbing can always be explicitly disabled via `set -f`. Edited.

Comment: @chepner consecutive whitespace characters are removed _only_ if `$IFS` equals its default value. [Prooflink](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSH).

Comment: Ah, right. Definitely mention that globbing should be turned off, though.